# load data local infile ignore line if a value exists

Tags: mysql, text, load

There is a table with some data in it, I'm inserting additional data from txt file with this function:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'users.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE users2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4) set login=@col1,name=@col1,balance=@col2,email=@col3,reg_date=@col4;
```

It works, but if login already exists with a different balance, it creates a row with a duplicate login and a different balance.

I need the function to **ignore** the line **if** the login exists. Can anybody help me with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a unique index on the login field.

```
ALTER TABLE USER2 add UNIQUE KEY(login);
```

thats all

Comment: Thanks! That did it.